# MongoDB inconsistent results with n > nscanned in explain

Tags: mongodb

Mongo 2.4.1, 2-member replica set with arbiter

I have what I think is a pretty simple query returning inconsistent results:

```js
objects = db.collection.find({'field.id': my_id, 'field1': None, 'field2': 'value'})
```

I'm getting 77 objects back, but there are 248 objects in the collection that match that query.  My suspicion is that the query optimizer is doing something I don't expect.  None of the indexes on collection are sparse.

In the .explain() for the above query, I get

```js
{cursor: 'BtreeCursor field.id_1', n: 283, nscanned: 77}
```

Why is nscanned less than 283?

I should also note that while the 77-length result is pretty consistent, occasionally the exact same query will return a result with 238 documents in it.

EDIT: full .explain() included below.  I noticed it looks at `BtreeCursor field.id_1` twice.  Is that normal?

```js
{
    "nYields": 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans": 1011,
    "allPlans": [
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field2_1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field2": [
                    ["moment", "moment"]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 78,
            "nscanned": 78,
            "n": 0
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field.id_1_field3_1_field2_1_field1_1_created_at_-1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field1": [
                    [null, null]
                ],
                "created_at": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field3": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field2": [
                    ["moment", "moment"]
                ],
                "field.id": [
                    ["oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d", "oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d"]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 78,
            "nscanned": 78,
            "n": 78
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field1_1_field3_1_field4_1_field5_-1_field2_1_created_at_-1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field4": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field3": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field1": [
                    [null, null]
                ],
                "created_at": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field5": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field2": [
                    ["moment", "moment"]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 78,
            "nscanned": 78,
            "n": 0
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field1_1_field3_1_field4_1_field2_1_created_at_-1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field1": [
                    [null, null]
                ],
                "created_at": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field4": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field2": [
                    ["moment", "moment"]
                ],
                "field3": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 78,
            "nscanned": 78,
            "n": 0
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field1_-1_created_at_-1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field1": [
                    [null, null]
                ],
                "created_at": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 78,
            "nscanned": 78,
            "n": 0
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field.id_1_field3_1_field1_1_created_at_-1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field1": [
                    [null, null]
                ],
                "created_at": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field3": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field.id": [
                    ["oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d", "oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d"]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 78,
            "nscanned": 78,
            "n": 78
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field.id_1_field6_1_field2_1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field6": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field2": [
                    ["moment", "moment"]
                ],
                "field.id": [
                    ["oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d", "oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d"]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 76,
            "nscanned": 77,
            "n": 76
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field.id_1_field7_1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field7": [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement": 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "field.id": [
                    ["oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d", "oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d"]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 78,
            "nscanned": 78,
            "n": 71
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field.id_1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field.id": [
                    ["oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d", "oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d"]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 78,
            "nscanned": 78,
            "n": 77
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BtreeCursor field.id_1",
            "indexBounds": {
                "field.id": [
                    ["oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d", "oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d"]
                ]
            },
            "nscannedObjects": 77,
            "nscanned": 77,
            "n": 72
        },
        {
            "cursor": "BasicCursor",
            "indexBounds": {},
            "nscannedObjects": 77,
            "nscanned": 77,
            "n": 0
        }
    ], 
    "millis": 14, 
    "nChunkSkips": 0, 
    "server": "c3:10003", 
    "n": 283, 
    "cursor": "BtreeCursor field.id_1",
    "oldPlan": {
        "cursor": "BtreeCursor field.id_1",
        "indexBounds": {
            "field.id": [
                ["oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d", "oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d"]
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "scanAndOrder": false, 
    "indexBounds": {
        "field.id": [
            ["oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d", "oid-50eba1a2256b4738d0e5254d"]
        ]
    }, 
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 1000, 
    "isMultiKey": false, 
    "indexOnly": false, 
    "nscanned": 77, 
    "nscannedObjects": 77
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the full explain?

Comment: I came across https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9856. Might this behavior be a symptom of multiple indexes?

Comment: that server ticket is not related.  however, I suspect this is because you have arrays involved in the query and some of your indexes are multikey indexes.  Can you show a sample document from the collection?  Or at least confirm which of the fields in the document are array fields?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have a **sparse** index.

- `n` = number of documents that match the query selection criteria
- `nscanned` = number of documents or index entries scanned during the database operation

If you have a [sparse index](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/index-sparse/), the index will not contain any entry for objects that do not have the index keys.

From the looks of your query, mongodb is indeed using the index for `field1` and your query is searching for `null` values for that field. So check if your index is sparse -- that's most likely the cause.